# How to type cast Any dynamically in scala?

Tags: java, scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I want to convert "Any" object into an object of runtime type. Based on the class name (string) at the runtime, how do I convert an ANY object to actual object?

I tried using converting class name into class object using Class.forName

```scala
val clazz = Class.forName("my.package.Animal")
val any: Any = Animal(1, "simba")
any.asInstanceOf[clazz] // Compilation Error // Looking for a solution
```

Comment: May I ask, why do you need this? I hope there are better alternatives that a runtime cast.

Comment: thanks @luis-miguel-mejía-suárez. I stored POJO objects in a file as byte arrays. And I have a mapping of files to objects. When I am trying to read POJOs from file, I have to convert them to right objects.

Comment: But why do you need to cast? Are you going to call methods on those objects? How will you know at compile time which methods are available if the cast is dynamic?

Comment: I have to call bunch of setter functions using these objects. Guess I can do a pattern match and set them

Comment: @sen I know there could be reasons that would not allow you. But, I would suggest you to change those **POJOS** to **Case Classes** and use a serializer, deserializer that is capable of returning correct types like [**Circe**](https://github.com/circe/circe) would do for JSONs. - Now, assuming you can not change the code, can you share a real use case of your code? Like, how do you read them, how do you call the setters and how would you want to cast them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

- compiler toolbox

  ```
  package my.package

  import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  case class Animal(id: Int, name: String)

  object App {    
    val any: Any = Animal(1, "simba")
    val className = "my.package.Animal"

    val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val tb = mirror.mkToolBox()
    tb.eval(tb.parse(
      s"""
        import my.package.App._
        val animal = any.asInstanceOf[$className]
        println(animal.id)
        println(animal.name)
      """))
  }
  ```

`libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value`

`libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value`

- or Scala reflection

  ```
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val classSymbol = mirror.staticClass(className)
  val typ = classSymbol.toType
  val idMethodSymbol = typ.decl(TermName("id")).asMethod
  val nameMethodSymbol = typ.decl(TermName("name")).asMethod
  val instanceMirror = mirror.reflect(any)
  val idMethodMirror = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(idMethodSymbol)
  val nameMethodMirror = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(nameMethodSymbol)
  println(idMethodMirror())
  println(nameMethodMirror())
  ```

`libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value`

- or Java reflection

  ```
  val clazz = Class.forName(className)
  val idMethod = clazz.getMethod("id")
  val nameMethod = clazz.getMethod("name")
  println(idMethod.invoke(any))
  println(nameMethod.invoke(any))
  ```